# Struct is incorrectly aligned: System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling, typeloadexception, structlayout

I'm trying to create the following struct in C#, its a complex struct which is based on a C one, I tried most of the marshaling options, but I always get 'System.TypeLoadException'.

(Additional information: Could not load type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.COMPLEX_STRUCT' from assembly 'WindowsFormsApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 8 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.)

Regarding IPV6_ADDR struct, I tried both LayoutKind.Explicit and LayoutKind.Sequential,
and both:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
public string Addr;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
public byte[] Addr;
```

I'm on a x64 machine, but the IPV6_ADDR struct is aligned to 8 bytes, so I can't figure out what is the problem.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct IPV4_ADDR
{
    public uint Addr;
    public uint SubnetNumBits;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
public struct IPV6_ADDR
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string Addr;
    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public uint SubnetNumBits;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
public struct COMPLEX_STRUCT
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte A;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte B;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte C;

    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte D;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public byte E;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public IPV4_ADDR IPv4;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public IPV6_ADDR IPv6;

    [FieldOffset(28)]
    public ushort F;
}
```

Original C structs I am trying to mimic:

```
typedef struct _IPV4_ADDR
{
    uint32_t Addr;
    uint32_t SubnetNumBits;
} IPV4_ADDR, *PIPV4_ADDR;

typedef struct _IPV6_ADDR
{
    uint8_t  Addr[16];
    uint32_t SubnetNumBits;
} IPV6_ADDR, *PIPV6_ADDR;

typedef struct _COMPLEX_STRUCT
{
    uint8_t A;
    uint8_t B;
    uint8_t C;
    uint8_t D;
    uint8_t E;
    uint8_t Rsvd[3];
    union {
        IPV4_ADDR IPv4;
        IPV6_ADDR IPv6;
    } u;
    uint16_t F;
} COMPLEX_STRUCT, *PCOMPLEX_STRUCT;
```

Comment: @TyCobb has it. Because strings are managed by the .NET run-time, you can't overlay a struct that has a string with one that doesn't also have a string at the same local offset.

Comment: OK Thx, I really don't mind switching from string to byte[] / char[], but I tried that as well, and still no good

Comment: I have added the original structs to your question. Please delete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your original structs and looking at other implementations for IPV4 and IPV6 structs, I see that other implementations use `byte[4]` for IPV4's address.

I can't guarantee the results will be correct, but if you are able to change IPV4 and IPV6 to both use a `byte[]` instead, your error will go away.

You cannot mix and match as you found. The only other option I can think of to try is see if it will allow you to use `IntPtr` to get the location of the memory and then use [Marshal.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy.aspx) to grab the data.

Even though once you get them working, I cannot guarantee your results will be correct though.

Comment: I do want to union them, I'm converting a C struct that has union of the IPV4 and IPV6 fields.

I really don't mind switching from string to byte[] / char[], but I tried that as well, and still no good

Comment: @n00b Probably the only way it will work is if you split the byte[] between 2 `ulongs`. Have a FieldOffset(0) and FieldOffset(8) and then merge the 2 longs back into a single byte[] when you need to work with the data (method on the struct).

Comment: @n00b Can you please also show the actual structs you are trying to mimic? I am beginning to think you're IPVx structs are supposed to be using `IntPtr` instead of `unint` and `string`.

Comment: Thanks @TyCobb, original structs below